# Calculations before_validation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two model relationship :

```
class Totalsold < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :qty, :total_cost, :date, :price_id, :price_attributes
  belongs_to :price
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :price
  before_validation :calculation_total_cost

  private

  def calculation_total_cost
    @price = Price.where(:id => price_id).first
    if qty.nil?
     self.qty = 0
    end
    self.total_cost = qty.to_f * @price.cost
  end
end

class Totalsold < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :cost
 has_many :totalsolds
end
```

`calculation_total_cost` method successfully post `total_cost` calculation from `qty` * `cost` `before_validation`. isn't good? because I'm using multiple create and see log [here](http://pastebin.com/um6k61ak) (I'm using pastebin for paste apps log) when submit form. 
Is there another way for my case? something solution for that better performance.

This is create method :

```
def create
  @totalsolds = params[:totalsolds].values.collect { |ts| Totalsold.new(ts) }
     if @totalsolds.all?(&:valid?)
      @totalsolds.each(&:save!)
      redirect_to lhg_path
     else
      render :action => 'new'
     end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it more efficient, you'll need to do the following:

> - Reduce `save` calls to 1 per object
> - Move your function to `before_save`
> - Remove any unnecessary queries from your callback

---

**Create**

Firstly, you need to make your `create` method more efficient. Currently, you're cycling through the `params[:totalsolds]` hash, and running validation & save requests every time. It just looks very cumbersome to me:

```
def create
  totalsold = params[:totalsolds]

  for total in totalsold do
     if total.save #-> should invoke validation
      redirect_to lhg_path
     else
      render :action => 'new'
     end
end
```

**Before Save**

Currently, you're calling `before_validation`. This means every time you validate an `ActiveRecord` object, your callback will be running. This is inefficient, although might be part of the way your app works

I would move this to the [`before_save`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) callback:

```
before_save :set_qty
before_save :calculate_total_cost

private

def set_qty
    self.qty = 0 if qty.nil?
end

def calculate_total_cost
    price = Price.find(price_id).cost
    total_cost = qty * price #-> qty doesn't need to be float (I think)
end
```

**Unnecessary Queries**

Your main problem is you're using a lot of queries which you don't need. Prime example: `Price.where(:id => price_id).first` HIGHLY inefficient -- just use `find` to pull a single record (as you're dealing with the primary key)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: thanks @RichPeck, your explanations are very detailed and clear. btw, why use this method `totalsold.save` for save in array? because I use it and got this error : `undefined method 'save' for #<Array:0x4b58bc0>`